# How do I delete all records related another record and greater than a certain threshold efficiently?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm trying to delete all notifications older than the first 99 for every user. Here's what I'm currently doing in rails:

```
User.all.each do |u|
  u.notifications.order('created_at DESC').offset(99).destory_all
end
```

This works fine, but it's horribly inefficient. You end up with a lookup for every user plus a delete query for every notification.

How would I go about doing this in a single query or at least more efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks pretty good so far. Here are a few improvements I can think of

When call user, use `.includes` to eager-load their notifications and `.find_each` for batching.

```
User.includes(:notifications).find_each do |u|
  ...
end
```

You also may try wrapping your call in an `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction` block

ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do 
  User.all.each do |u|
    u.notifications.order('created_at DESC').offset(99).destory_all
  end
end

This will perform a batch transaction, instead of one-by-one.

Now, if you **really** want to make an improvement, use `.delete_all` instead of `.destroy_all`. This will cause deletions in purse SQL. **Warning: Ruby callbacks like `before_destroy` will not get called**